# Geofencing using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geofencing

I would like to inquire about the ships within the designated area, the following picture:

[image]

The latitude and longitude drawn is

```
118.868653 32.199966,
118.873224 32.192503,
118.876336 32.184894,
118.872967 32.183551,
118.868901 32.188654,
118.866492 32.193383,
118.864319 32.198767
```

sql code

```
create table ship_location(
    id          integer default nextval('ship_location_seq'::regclass) not null
        primary key,
    site_id     varchar(64),
    mmsi        varchar(64),
    lon_str     varchar(64),
    lat_str     varchar(64),
    create_time timestamp,
    m_location  geometry(Point, 4326)
);

select ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (118.868653 32.199966,118.873224 32.192503,118.876336 32.184894,118.872967 32.183551,118.868901 32.188654,118.866492 32.193383,118.864319 32.198767) '))
```

error message

```
[XX000] ERROR: lwpoly_from_lwlines: shell must be closed
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 7):

Your linestring has to end in the same point as it starts to create a polygon from it:

`select ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (118.868653 32.199966,118.873224 32.192503,118.876336 32.184894,118.872967 32.183551,118.868901 32.188654,118.866492 32.193383,118.864319 32.198767, 118.868653 32.199966), 4326'))`

Then you can select ships within it like this:

```
select * from ship_location
where st_intersects(m_location, 
    ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (118.868653 32.199966,118.873224 32.192503,118.876336 32.184894,118.872967 32.183551,118.868901 32.188654,118.866492 32.193383,118.864319 32.198767, 118.868653 32.199966), 4326')))
```